# Check Checkbox using ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have HTML checkbox and I'm trying to check it using the script I received as an ajax response.
Here is my HTML:

```
<form class="form-vertical sms-settings-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div data-toggle="tooltip" title="SMS to the customer at the time of sale." class="form-group opt-transport">
               <label for="sale-sms">Sale SMS</label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="sale-sms" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Send" data-off="Don't Sent">
         </div>
        <textarea data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-control" id="sale-sms-content"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success sms-settings-btn">Save Settings</button>
</form>
```

Here is my AJAX request.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("ajax-req-handler.php", {key: "load-saved-settings"}, function(data){ $(".exec-ajax-script").html(data); });
});
```

Here is my `ajax-req-handler.php`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM settings";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if(num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $setting_name = $row['name'];
        if($id == 1 && $setting_name == 'sale-sms') $sms_content = $row['value'];
        if($id == 2 && $setting_name == 'send-sms') $send_sms = $row['value'];

    }
} ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".sms-settings-form #sale-sms").prop(<?php echo ($send_sms == 1) ? "'checked', 'checked'" : ""; ?>);
        $(".sms-settings-form textarea").val("<?php echo $sms_content; ?>");
    });

</script> <?php
```

And Here is the code that I'm getting as AJAX resopnse

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".sms-settings-form #sale-sms").prop('checked', 'checked');
        $(".sms-settings-form textarea").val("Hello [name], Your mobile number is [mobile]. your total amount is Rs. [total] out of which you paid Rs. [paid] and your due amount is [due] for the bill number # [bill] on [date] ");
    });

</script>
```

The response seems Ok but still, it's not setting the value of my checkbox to checked. I tried copying the response and pasted in my 1st file (file where checkbox is defined and ajax request is initiated). It's working there. The problem is only with ajax response

Comment: Note that `".sms-settings-form #sale-sms"` is redundant if your HTML is valid - IDs are unique, so you can just do "#sale-sms".

Comment: maybe the document.ready will not trigger since this is an ajax request

Comment: @CertainPerformance I tried removing the class `.sms-settings-form` but this didn't work

Comment: @zainulabdeen then your HTML is invalid. Make sure there is only ever exactly one element matching a particular ID string in a document.

Comment: @Shwrk I already tried removing `document.ready` from my ajax response but the problem remains

Comment: hi.. could you modify the script to log `$(".sms-settings-form #sale-sms").length`. this will tell you if the selector is matching your checkbox

Comment: okay let check it

Comment: @Shwrk `$(".sms-settings-form #sale-sms").length` is returning 1

Comment: I also added my HTML please check it also. is there something wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem Here is not that the script is not adding `checked` attribute to the `<input type='checkbox'>`. script is working as expected and adding `checked` attribute. The problem is it's not just a checkbox instead it's toggle switch where `<input type='checkbox'>` is set to `display: none` by default and also it adds and remove some classes to it's self defined `div` with `class='toggle'` whenever clicked, to show whether the switch is `On` or `Off`. 
So, doing this `$(".sms-settings-form #sale-sms").attr('checked', true);` is not enough because this will only check the checkbox but it will not effect the user interface, The toggle switch will still appear to be 'Off' even though it's not.
To effect the UI we need to add and remove some classes from `.toggle`
Here is the code that will work:

```
$(".sms-settings-form #sale-sms").attr('checked', true);
$(".sms-settings-form textarea").val("Hello [name], Your mobile number is [mobile]. your total amount is Rs. [total] out of which you paid Rs. [paid] and your due amount is [due] for the bill number # [bill] on [date] ");
$(".toggle").addClass('btn-primary');
$(".toggle").removeClass('btn-default');
$(".toggle").removeClass('off');
```

Comment: Yes, This is the solution and it is working now. The reason why my own answer is not accepted is that the StackOverflow allows you to accept your answer after 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but put all of your code in Javascript instead of injecting it into the HTML dom.

```
$.ajax( {
  url: 'ajax-req-handler.php',
  data: { key: 'load-saved-settings' },
  dataType: 'json'
} ).done( function( data ) {

  if( data.send_sms === 1 ) {
    $(".sms-settings-form #sale-sms").prop('checked', true);
  }

  $(".sms-settings-form textarea").val( data.textarea );

} );
```

And for PHP; instead do.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM settings";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if(num_rows($result)>0){
  while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
      $id = $row['id'];
      $setting_name = $row['name'];
      if($id == 1 && $setting_name == 'sale-sms') $sms_content = $row['value'];
      if($id == 2 && $setting_name == 'send-sms') $send_sms = $row['value'];

  }
}

echo json_encode( array(
  'send_sms' => $send_sms,
  'textarea' => $sms_content
) );
```

Comment: Nice. this improved my code. but unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for putting your efforts. but I already tried `prop('checked', true);`

Comment: Hmm, I just tested the code I gave you and it works flawlessly. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Your code is okay. I finally detected where the problem is. There is something wrong with my code. Now, I'm Going to answer my own question

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with ajax-req-handler.php

You have while loop, and must be processing multiple records.
If you are getting multiple records, then document ready section written in jquery will execute according to last record in the data set.

Please provide sample data, to review it accordingly.

Comment: But there's nothing wrong with the script I'm getting as ajax response.