# Change toggle status to previous state

Tags: jquery

I am struggling to change the toggle checkbox to previous state(based on the ajax result). If my ajax result is "false" then I want it go to previous state. Because ajax is called after user click the toggle. And once user clicks state is changing and only after that I am doing ajax control.

Html code block is:

```
<form method="post" id="toggleForm_{{$detail['id']}}">
    <input data-id="{{$detail['id']}}" id="{{$detail['id']}}" class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" {{ $detail['status'] == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
    <input type="hidden" class="statusForDetail" value="{{$detail['id']}}" page="sections-set-status" >
</form>
```

and my jQuery is :

```
function onToggle() {
    var page = $(".statusForDetail").attr('page');
    $(".statusForDetail").each((index, element) => {
        let id = $(element).val();
        let sid = $(element).val();
        $('#toggleForm_'+id).find('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
            this.checked ?  updateStatus(1,id, page,sid):  updateStatus(0,id, page,sid);
        });
    });
}
function updateStatus(status_val,id, page,sid) {

        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: "/admin/" + page,
            data: {status: status_val, id: id},
            success: function (result) {
                if (result[0] == "Success!") {
                    if (status_val == 1) {
                        $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='green' font size='2px'> : "+ result[0] + result[1] +"</font>").fadeOut(1500);
                      
                    } else if (status_val == 0) {
                       
                        $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='green' font size='2px'> : "+ result[0] + result[1] +"</font>").fadeOut(1500);
                    
                    }
                } else {

                        if (status_val == 1) {
                        $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='red'>" + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
                        $('#toggleForm_'+sid).prop('checked', false);
                    } else if (status_val == 0) {
                        $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='red'>" + result[0] + result[1] +  "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
                        $('#toggleForm_'+sid).prop('checked', true);
                    }
                }
            }, error: function () {

            }
        });
  }
```

as you see I am sending data to my php and according to the result I am making toggle on or off. but the line :

```
$('#toggleForm_'+sid).prop('checked', false);
```

does not work at all. The state does not change in my html page. even I am getting `"false"` from php it changes to on or off respectively. However, when I get the `"false"` result from php I want switch to go to previous state (because user pressed the toggle and it's state has been changed already until ajax part).
[image]
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: your targeting the form "toggleForm_" not the checkbox, so perhaps something like ```$('#toggleForm_'+sid).find('input:checkbox:first').attr('checked', 'checked'); ``` ?

Comment: nope, I have tested that already. not working. But what I found is the reference: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606279/check-checkbox-using-ajax-response  when I remove the class `$(".toggle").removeClass('off');` then activate->deactivate is disabling but not vice versa ..

Comment: so you can reference the check box correctly yes? in that case what about using ```$(".toggle").toggleclass("off")``` that should toggle the class that's applied

Comment: Yes, actually when I use `$(".toggle").removeClass('off')`  it  prevents to change the state from on to off but not vice versa. Tried what you adviced but it warns me that unresolved method or function toggleclass().. not worked.

Comment: thats odd as that really should work (https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) ok try this then ```$(".toggle").hasClass( "off" ) ? $(".toggle").removeClass("off") : $(".toggle").addClass('off') ```

Comment: now it worked but now it changes all toggles status when i press one of them. Should I attain any id each of them ? Also after pressing several times it changes, however it is expected not to change.

Comment: yes as your targeting everything with the class ".toggle" so your need to use an id if you want to target a specific checkbox it depends on witch one your want to update

Comment: But it is weird. In my code, there is not any class like .toggle. how can I add id in that case? check my html code above please.

Comment: you have ``id="{{$detail['id']}}```

on the check box, if you know what that is you can target that, I supect the ".toggle" must be matching on class="toggle-class" somehow, another idea might be to use the change event 

```$('#toggleForm_'+id).find('input[type="checkbox"]')```

to add a reference to the check box to us in the ajax call ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247722/discussion-between-orkhan-orkhan-and-patrick-hume).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could pass or set a reference of the checkbox that probably be easier, something like:

```js
let cbRef = null;
function onToggle() {
    var page = $(".statusForDetail").attr('page');
    $(".statusForDetail").each((index, element) => {
        let id = $(element).val();
        let sid = $(element).val();
        $('#toggleForm_'+id).find('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
                cbRef = $(this);
            this.checked ?  updateStatus(1,id, page,sid):  updateStatus(0,id, page,sid);
        });
    });
}
function updateStatus(status_val,id, page,sid) {

        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: "/admin/" + page,
            data: {status: status_val, id: id},
            success: function (result) {
                if (result[0] == "Success!") {
                    if (status_val == 1) {
                        $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='green' font size='2px'> : "+ result[0] + result[1] +"</font>").fadeOut(1500);
                      
                    } else if (status_val == 0) {
                       
                        $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='green' font size='2px'> : "+ result[0] + result[1] +"</font>").fadeOut(1500);
                    
                    }
                } else {

                        if (status_val == 1) {
                        $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='red'>" + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
                        cbRef.prop('checked', false);
                    } else if (status_val == 0) {
                        $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='red'>" + result[0] + result[1] +  "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
                        cbRef.prop('checked', true);
                    }
                }
            }, error: function () {

            }
        });
  }
```

or

```js
function onToggle() {
  var page = $(".statusForDetail").attr('page');
  $(".statusForDetail").each((index, element) => {
    let id = $(element).val();
    let sid = $(element).val();
    $('#toggleForm_' + id).find('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
      this.checked ? updateStatus(1, id, page, sid, $(this)) : updateStatus(0, id, page, sid, $(this));
    });
  });
}

function updateStatus(status_val, id, page, sid, cbRef) {

  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/" + page,
    data: {
      status: status_val,
      id: id
    },
    success: function(result) {
      if (result[0] == "Success!") {
        if (status_val == 1) {
          $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='green' font size='2px'> : " + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);

        } else if (status_val == 0) {

          $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='green' font size='2px'> : " + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);

        }
      } else {

        if (status_val == 1) {
          $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='red'>" + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
          cbRef.prop('checked', false);
        } else if (status_val == 0) {
          $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='red'>" + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
          cbRef.prop('checked', true);
        }
      }
    },
    error: function() {

    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The second one worked but with minor issue. The case is that it always accept first click, only after that it disables to toggle as expected. For example if the toggle position is off, then it allow me to press to make it on, only from this point it starts to work. I think it is because jquery does not take it's first state as toggled. However, this is main aim here to prevent the change of toggle based on result of ajax. Maybe ajax call must be completed firs then toggle part? Unless it is completed deactivate the toggle process?

Comment: And interestingly when I remove `data-toggle="toggle"` part from my html page then it works as expected but it shows me simple checkbox instead of colorful toggle.

Comment: Tried to add `$("#sce_"+sid).bootstrapToggle('off');` below of `cbRef.prop('checked', true);` code in order to turn on and off toggle as well along with checkbox, and ended up on endless loop (status turns on and off constantly once I press it).

Comment: try adding

 ```event.preventDefault()``` 

to the change event of the 

```$('#toggleForm_' + id).find('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {```

if it's looping like that its because the bootstrap is triggering the change event, could you call the ajax check on page load and disable the checkboxes based on its result that way wouldn't need to call it on the change event ?

Comment: Tried that already, but did not help. Interestingly it goes to the if and then else because of the `.change()` event. So can not take control of that. But if I use ` `$("#toggleForm_"+sid).bootstrapToggle('off');` instead of `$("#sce_"+sid).bootstrapToggle('off');` it works as expected but this time when you press the button the design is destroyed. but functionality is working. Maybe there is somehow we can add some attribute and call that? would that help? fisrt version I have made like that. I have called ajax first then set a state but the same problem was there therefore changed the style

Comment: Also, even if I get the status from the db and disable required ones, still user should be able to press and change the state. then what will happen if user presses the button? Don't we still need event controller here?

Comment: if it destroys the design (which is odd) i assume its using bootstap css, , can you apply css to style the checkbox to look the same as before by applying your own class to it ? otherwise you could  always call jquery trigger and pass a parameter that you check to prevent the re-firing call to ajax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401538/passing-parameters-on-jquery-trigger , if you want the user to be able to still be able to actually be able to toggle the checkbox if you know the status up front then you could code it so that rather than disabling the checkbox you use a flag say an ....

Comment: ... array that you set on page load and if check checkbox in question its in the array you simply reset its state on change so it just reverts in the change event and dose nothing otherwise allow to stay active, why if you just going to set the status back anyway do you want the user to be able to toggle it though out of interest?

Comment: User (Admin) is changing the category status so yes, admin needs to be able to change the status. It is a part from admin panel. The trigger solution which you referred me no luck so far. I was not able to make it work, however trying hard :) I think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247723/discussion-between-orkhan-orkhan-and-patrick-hume).

Answer (score 1):

there is also a bind method too

```js
function onToggle() {
  var page = $(".statusForDetail").attr('page');
  $(".statusForDetail").each((index, element) => {
    let id = $(element).val();
    let sid = $(element).val();
    $('#toggleForm_' + id).find('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
      this.checked ? updateStatus(1, id, page, sid, $(this)) : updateStatus(0, id, page, sid, $(this));
    });
  });
}

function updateStatus(status_val, id, page, sid, cbRef) {

  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/" + page,
    data: {
      status: status_val,
      id: id
    },
    success: function(cbRef, result) {
      if (result[0] == "Success!") {
        if (status_val == 1) {
          $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='green' font size='2px'> : " + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);

        } else if (status_val == 0) {

          $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='green' font size='2px'> : " + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);

        }
      } else {

        if (status_val == 1) {
          $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='red'>" + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
          cbRef.prop('checked', false);
        } else if (status_val == 0) {
          $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='red'>" + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
          cbRef.prop('checked', true);
        }
      }
    }.bind(this, cbRef)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be something like this for custom toggle

```
 $(".statusForDetail").each((index, element) => {
   let id = $(element).val();
   let sid = $(element).val();
   $('#toggleForm_' + id).find('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
     this.checked ? updateStatus(1, id, page, sid) : updateStatus(0, id, page, sid);
   });
   $('#toggleForm_' + id).find('input[type="checkbox"]').on("custom", function(event) {
            //toggel code here 
   });
 });
```

and then in the part where you passed or set the reference to the checkbox

```
cbRef.trigger( "custom" );
```

are you able to knock up a jsfiddle as hard to help based off partial code/html?

Comment: I would like but can't figure it out. I actually put all the code I have. It is the second day 48 hours and I am still was not able to fix a toggle. I am not a professional in js/jquery therefore struggling a lot. Can you please let me know where should I use `cbRef.trigger( "custom" );` ? and what should I insert in the part where you mentioned as `//toggel code here` ?

Comment: yer its not easy if you new to JS sorry im probably not doing a great job at helping, see new answer , hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

something like this hopefully:

```
function onToggle() {
  var page = $(".statusForDetail").attr('page');
  $(".statusForDetail").each((index, element) => {
    let id = $(element).val();
    let sid = $(element).val();
    $('#toggleForm_' + id).find('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
      this.checked ? updateStatus(1, id, page, sid, $(this)) : updateStatus(0, id, page, sid, $(this));
    });
    $('#toggleForm_' + id).find('input[type="checkbox"]').on("custom", function(event, checkState) {
      $(this).prop('checked', checkState);
    });
  });
}

function updateStatus(status_val, id, page, sid, cbRef) {
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/" + page,
    data: {
      status: status_val,
      id: id
    },
    success: function(cbRef, result) {
      if (result[0] == "Success!") {
        if (status_val == 1) {
          $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='green' font size='2px'> : " + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
        } else if (status_val == 0) {
          $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='green' font size='2px'> : " + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
        }
      } else {
        if (status_val == 1) {
          $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='red'>" + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
          cbRef.trigger("custom", [false]);
        } else if (status_val == 0) {
          $("#updatedAt").fadeIn(0).html("<font color='red'>" + result[0] + result[1] + "</font>").fadeOut(1500);
          cbRef.trigger("custom", [true]);
        }
      }
    }.bind(this, cbRef)
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support Patrick. I appreciate and would like to let you know that you let me learn too much things.  I am just so nervous as I am unable to figure it out. Tried your code but again there is an issue : it works only in the second press of the button not from the first press. This issue happened before (another code alternative) as well. I don't understand why it doesn't work in the second attempt? when the `result == success`  it works as expected. But when the ajax `result != success` it works after second attempt. toggle state changes even it gets fail from ajax

Comment: I mean if ajax `result != success` I shouldn't be able to press the button, however I can press only once, after that it is disabled and works as expected. Again, issue only has if the `result != success`.

Comment: so the if logic needs tweaking , so to clarify, it the 

```sucesss === false``` { note you should use 3 equals no 2 =)  }

that is the only time when it checks 

```status_val```

 and based on that it sets the checkbox state, that's the only time it does this, so if  

```sucesss === true```

 It's not currently setting the checkbox state, is that what you want it to do? when it comes back as 

```sucesss === true```

is it then setting the checkbox check state correctly? When you say disabled, I thought it was nearly setting the checkbox check state  ....

Comment: ... based on the ```status_val``` ? What's the difference between the first and second time you click it, is the code going down a different code path? you can use

 ```debugger;```  

to force the browser to debug from where ever you place line of that code in your js , you may need to open your browser debugger window, you can then follow the code though to trace whats happening, I'm glad your learning and that I'm kinda helping

Comment: There is not any different path when user clicks and etc. When I say 'disabled' I mean state is getting back when you press (feels like disabled - which is ok). What I was trying to say is that, the code you provided works fine at all except one case. So, when the admin opens the html page he see the table and different categories with different states. Because we are getting state from html : `{{ $detail['status'] == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}`. So far is ok. if the ajax result returns false after user press, in the first attempt toggle switches (which it shouldn't) but after second attempt it ...

Comment: starts to work as expected and toggle does not changes the state. This is the only issue. Now, I am trying to find why in the first attempt Jquery lets it to switch, as we have prevented this.

Comment: sorry is a bit slow to catch on =S i am just trying to make sure I fully understand, so... the first time when user click ajax returns result[0] === "false!", then it would go into the else block and check status_val  and based on that it will set checkbox state to false or true based on that When you click it the second time and it works does it follow the same pattern and do the same thing? is your project on GitHub I could pull it down and work on it for you, or if you're ok with it can do a screen share via ms teams, webex, skype, zoom, slack, or discord?

Comment: Also out of interest as your using {{ ... }} HTML code block this by chance and angular or react project, just wondering

Comment: Zoom is okay if you don't mind. I can show you what is going on, even I can give you live website to check it out what is going on there. So you could get my point what I mean.  It is a Laravel based project. Just intended to use jQuery first time in my life and I messed up. How can I give the url please let me know ? I also tried to debug but was not clear to me to be honest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247724/discussion-between-orkhan-orkhan-and-patrick-hume).